# How can I make all applications use Nemo's file selection dialog instead of Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, gedit, evince, nemo

I switched to nemo a long time ago, because I think it's superior to nautilus in many ways. One small thing bothers me however:

Whenever I want to open a document in gedit (or evince, but I'm sure there are other programs as well) not the nemo file-selection window appears but the nautilus one.

I did of course replace nemo with nautilus as suggested in a lot of other posts:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

and

```
 xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

and also did

```
 ln -s /usr/bin/nemo /usr/local/bin/nautilus
```

in order to completely replace nautilus, but this doesn't help. Which program/executable is triggered when hitting open (Ctrl+o) in gedit/evince?

Comment: How did you install nemo?

Comment: from here: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/nemo. They say, that they are not responsible for this "bug" since this happens because of nautilus

Comment: Does this happen in say web browsers and **all** other applications with a save/open dialogue?

Comment: @wa4557: Can you point to the bug you are talking about?

Comment: @Jobin: Well I haven't submitted a bug report yet (I'm not even sure it is a proper bug)

Comment: @Xweque: No it does not happen with all(!) applications. Chromium for example opens the nemo dialog. Maybe only gtk3 apps(?)

Comment: Did anybody reported a bug for this? I think this is a bug, I'm just not sure to which package it would be attached to

Comment: the more I think about it, the less I think this is a bug. I think the thing is, that in GTK3 the GTK-filechooser dialog is just designed this way

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not a nemo vs nautilus issue. It's a GTK+2 vs GTK+3 issue. Apps written for GTK+2 will use the familiar-looking Humanity-themed file selection dialog, while apps written for GTK+3 will use the alien, hollow-looking default theme for GTK+3.

Unfortunately, the only way to get a consistent UX is to use all GTK+2 apps, or switch to a Qt-based DE like LXQT or KDE.

Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to run next commands:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

And check Nemo is default:

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

Also here exists a guide to change
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager

Comment: Wrong, but I don't have karma to burn. This is about the GTK file picker misfeature, not the default file manager.