# How can I force all applications to use Nemo's file selection dialog instead of Nautilus's one?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, ubuntu-gnome, nemo

A similar question has been already asked on this site. Here is the link:
[How can I make all applications use Nemo's file selection dialog instead of Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455747/how-can-i-make-all-applications-use-nemos-file-selection-dialog-instead-of-naut)

Anyway, this has been posted in 2014. Today (2020), I would like to know if something changed about this situation.